# How can I save and restore fragment state in bottom navigation material design?

Tags: java, android, web, mobile

Other fragments exist within bottom navigation fragment and contains data from the server! The data seems to be there as it loads quickly than before but the view gets destroyed and loads again delaying the process.

Comment: I'd suggest you link the documentation page for the exact navigation fragment you're using, or include some code with the question so that others can answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you load the fragment you need to check if the data is already there before making the network request again.

Let's say you call the network on "onCreateView" method. You have a global variable in your class.

```
class YourClass{
var someVariable = 0
...
//here your call network on "onCreateView" method

someVariable = callingNetWork.getValueFromNetWork()

}
```

onCreateView is called from fragment lifecycle, you cannot control how many times it will be called. So you need to check if already have the data. You need a logic like this:

```
if( someVariable == 0) { //Has not been modiefied yet
someVariable = callingNetWork.getValueFromNetWork()
}
//Don't need an else, if it's not equal to 0, you have already called the networkd and stored the value
```

Comment: Thanks man it worked! Just a little misunderstanding problem!